# php shortest version of calling a class

Tags: php, oop, backend

i saw a lot of ways that you can use to call a class inside another one in PHP and i want your opinion about the shortest version of calling a class.

lets say we have a class name view,
and another class name controller

```
class View 
{

private $data = array();

private $render = FALSE;

public function __construct($template , $datas = null)
{

    try {
        $file = strtolower($template) . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            if($datas > 0) {
                foreach($datas as $data) {
                    array_push($this->data, $data);
                }
            }
            $this->render = $file;
        } else {
            die('Template ' . $template . ' not found!');
        }
    }
    catch (customException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
}

public function __destruct()
{
    extract($this->data);
    include($this->render);

}
}
```

and

```
require_once "system/autoload.php";

class Controller {

function index() {
   $view = new View('something');
}
```

i know that i can use

```
 $view = new View('something');
```

or use OOP and extent and call a function from view inside controller like

```
$this->viewFunction();
```

but is there any way that i can call view class inside controller like this

```
View('something)
```

i want to make it shortest version possible
if it is not possible or i have to make change inside compiler well just give me the shortest version

thank you all

Comment: What task will you solve with this shortest solution?

Comment: Something similar to `__invoke`?

Comment: @GetSet it is not a yes or no, i search and did not find any better way so i am asking if anyone knows a better way

Comment: @u_mulder well i just thinking the shorter the code is the better

Comment: Obviously not..

Comment: Having excessive code (temporary variables when not needed) can be bad, but sometimes shorter code becomes less understandable and can be more prone to mistakes being made.

Comment: @u_mulder it is not a crime to ask question i'm just trying to increase my knowledge, ,sorry if my question was stupid for you

Comment: @NigelRen thank you, your comment was really helpful

Comment: @AhmadVahedi IMHO code length plays very little importance, what is more important is  readability of the code and that the code should abide by some principles such as SOLD, KISSm YAGNI etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely do this in PHP. Have a look at [magic methods, especially __invoke()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)

```
class View
{
    public function __invoke(string $template)
    {
        return $template;
    }
}
```

You can simply invoke it by doing

```
$view = new View();
$view('my template');
```